# FFMPEG: Complex Filter For Tiktok Videos

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

Could somebody please write a complex filter command that could create something that looks like this. The background is [background] and the clip is [base].
[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMdLM.jpg)

This is what I have, but it isn't working:

```
const scaleFilter = `[0:v]scale=${cropWidth}:0,crop=iw:ih[base];[1:v]scale=${cropWidth}:0,crop=iw:ih,pad=${cropWidth}:3*ih:0:0:color=black@0,format=rgba,setsar=1[background];[background][base]overlay=0:0:format=auto`;
```

For context, cropWidth is:

```
const width = metadata.streams[0].width;
const height = metadata.streams[0].height;
            
const cropWidth = Math.min(width, Math.floor((height * 9) / 16));
```

Comment: Please note, that we're not a code writing service. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and tell us what you tried so far and where you got stuck and why.